# C - ls optional flag

Tags: c, shell, unix, option-type, ls

I've got a basic shell program that can change directories using `cd` and list the files with `ls`. I want to extend this further by adding optional flags to the `ls` command. In particular, I want to implement the `ls -l` (lowercase 'ell') command whereby it shows a total sum of all file sizes on the line before the long listing. I'm not sure how I can implement this. My code I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 1024
#define DELIMS " \t\r\n"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *cmd;
  char line[MAX_LENGTH];

  while(1){
    printf("> ");
    if (!fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, stdin)) break;

    if ((cmd = strtok(line, DELIMS))) {
        char *arg = strtok(0, DELIMS);
        if (strcmp(cmd, "cd") == 0) {

        if (!arg) fprintf(stderr, "cd missing argument.\n");
        else {
            chdir(arg);
        } 
      } 
        else if (strcmp(cmd, "ls") == 0) {
        struct dirent **namelist;
        int n;
        n = scandir(".",&namelist,NULL,alphasort);
        if(n < 0)
        {
            perror("scandir");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
        while (n--)
        {
            printf("%s\n",namelist[n]->d_name);
            free(namelist[n]);
        }
        free(namelist);
        }
      }
        else if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most basic shell operates by recognizing a single command, followed by any flags/options to that command and any arguments to the command (or to one of its options). Any command can have options, and it's up to that command how the options are interpreted. If you can figure out how to allow any command to accept options, then you'll have the right idea. There are multiple ways of doing this, so I can't really recommend any one way.

Comment: Do pay very close attention to indentation when writing code, *especially* C code. You want bugs to be obvious and the structure to be as clear as possible so bugs don't sneak in.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that before this code spirals out of control in terms of complexity you'll want to push the code for each command into functions. A common pattern in C code is to have a simple lookup table for commands that have function pointers to the code they should run. This makes adding new commands trivial. Commands can be broken out into different files if necessary, making your system more modular.